# How to change the list of points to be generated automatically?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, leaflet, folium

How to change the list of points to be generated automatically?

I want to have access to a map on a website with an automatically generated list of points depending on which towns the user selects.

```js
var map_459983c9521af07ce47320ce3c2214fe = L.map(
  "map_459983c9521af07ce47320ce3c2214fe", {
    center: [52.40541, 16.93126],
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
    zoom: 12,
    zoomControl: true,
    preferCanvas: false,
  }
);
var marker_ae76a19f7fb53b7a60dc703d21711c33 = L.marker(
  [52.40541, 16.93126], {
    "color": "green",
    "fillColor": "green"
  }
).addTo(map_459983c9521af07ce47320ce3c2214fe);
var marker_34e05070c9ccfcb27e56a42b7858742d = L.marker(
  [52.7294, 15.24038], {
    "color": "red",
    "fillColor": "red"
  }
).addTo(map_459983c9521af07ce47320ce3c2214fe);
var poly_line_47526c6e001992597f7909d2b9bed3d2 = L.polyline(
  [
    [52.40541, 16.93126], ..., [52.7294, 15.24038]
  ], {
    "bubblingMouseEvents": true,
    "color": "blue",
    "dashArray": null,
    "dashOffset": null,
    "fill": false,
    "fillColor": "blue",
    "fillOpacity": 0.2,
    "fillRule": "evenodd",
    "lineCap": "round",
    "lineJoin": "round",
    "noClip": false,
    "opacity": 1,
    "smoothFactor": 1.0,
    "stroke": true,
    "weight": 2.5
  }
).addTo(map_459983c9521af07ce47320ce3c2214fe);
```

Comment: https://beta.im.ge/i/result-decorate.FMXvcF

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+generate+map+markers+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.